# Insert into 2 tables simultaneously but stop if there are errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have two tables in my SQL Server, Invoices and InvoiceDetails. 
Invoices:

```
Invoice  |  Date         |  Total     | Salesman
1001     |  10/10/2015   |  1000.00   |  101
```

InvoiceDetails:

```
ID  | Invoice          | ProductID  | Date       |Total   | Salesman
1   |  1001            | 1          | 10/10/2015 | 200.00 | 101
2   |  1001            | 2          | 10/10/2015 | 200.00 | 101
3   |  1001            | 3          | 10/10/2015 | 100.00 | 101
4   |  1001            | 4          | 10/10/2015 | 500.00 | 101
```

I would like to fill these two tables at the same time, meaning with just one sql query. I can use two insert statements as follows:

```
INSERT INTO InvoicesDetails(data) VALUES(data_to_insert)
INSERT INTO Invoices(data) VALUES(data_to_insert)
```

I need to insert into the InvoicesDetails first before inserting it in the Invoices. But the problem is, what if the last transaction is not successfully recorded into the InvoiceDetails table? In theInvoices table, the particular Invoice, 1001, would have a total of 1,000.00 but in the InvoiceDetails, it will just be 500.00 since it was not successful in inserting the last transaction of 500.00.

How do I implement inserts in one sql syntax on this situation?
Thank you!

Comment: The point of a transaction is to cover the *entire* operation (ie. both inserts) that must be atomic. The transaction will either then succeed when it is committed (and change to tables are guaranteed) or be rolled back (in which case neither table is updated).

Comment: Now, that aside: the fundamental problem still exists with a .. questionable schema. It would currently require (assuming an auto-identity pk) inserting into the InvoiceDetails (to get an Invoice ID), adding all the records to the InvoiceDetails (with the new Invoice ID), and then updating the recently Invoice with the cumulative total.

Comment: There are several different solutions to this, including 1) just doing it that way, 2) generating the Natural PK independently and bypassing identity insert 3) not including the total in the Invoice (but just use a SUM query) 4) having a distinct WorkOrder and BillOfWork table, etc. Also it appears that the Salesman column is poorly normalized (eg. can two different Sales people contribute to the same invoice?)

Comment: Yes Sir, I I know it is not yet normalized but I just wanted to make a point. I know that there shouldn't be any Salesman in the InvoiceDetails since it is in the Invoice Table already. What you are trying to point is correct but I'm afraid it is quite hard for me to understand yet. If you could just please give me an example syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible if I just make a commit and rollback syntax. Say if the database insert encounters an error once committed, I will just catch it in my Catch statement and execute a rollback. Is that a correct Idea?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, this is the point of transactions -- either both changes happen or neither.  These are well described in the documentation ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx)).

In your case, the code would look like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION insertboth
    INSERT INTO InvoicesDetails(data) VALUES(data_to_insert);
    INSERT INTO Invoices(data) VALUES(data_to_insert);
COMMIT TRANSACTION insertboth;
```

I would recommend that in addition to transactions you include `TRY`/`CATCH` blocks to catch many errors and encapsulate the logic in a stored procedure.

As a side note:  your data structure is fine.  You might want to be clear the `invoice` is the primary key of the `invoices` tables.

Comment: I'm still not a fan of the computed value as a 'soft' cyclic dependency.